# Unexpected output result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have encountered an unexpected situation.

I'm scraping words from the website
[SpanishDict.com](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/).

For example:
I search for the term `niño`, then `.py` gives me below result which exactly I wanted.

```
(nee-nyoh)
masculine or feminine noun
```

But when I search `que`, then `.py` gives me a totally `wrong result` as below;

> (kweh-behk)
>
> conjunction

According to [definition of que](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/que), `.py` should've give me a result like below;

```
(keh)
conjunction
```

So I'm wondering what's wrong with this?
Any idea?

Thanks

I have included my code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/"
search_keyword = input("input the keyword : ")
url = base_url + search_keyword
spanishdict_r = requests.get(url)
spanishdict_soup = BeautifulSoup(spanishdict_r.text, 'html.parser')

# Phonetic Alphabet
print(spanishdict_soup.find('span', {'class': 'dictionaryLink--369db'}).text)
# Part of Speech
print(spanishdict_soup.find('a', {'class': 'href--2RDqa'}).text)
# Meaning
```

Comment: You are access the html from English to Spanish tab when you want from Spanish to English. Nino is the same for bot, while que is different

Comment: @chitown88 I see. But how do I make it only search spanish to english part? I can't find out any address for this.

Comment: Ya I'm looking into that now. I might have an alternate solution for you. give me a minute

Comment: OK found it. Give me a minute or so to write up the code

Comment: Doesn't it work with the anchor "#translate-en"?

Comment: @Raphael Maybe it does, but I've only learned Python by myself a week, and this is my first code ever. So I don't understand how to fix this by adding #translate-en. Anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: "#translate-en" is given by www.spanishdict.com/query#translate-en it's not a python thing.

Comment: @Raphael I see. Sadly, I'm nearly zero based of html too.

Comment: ah. The solution below mine by Slobodan Ilic found it. Accept his answer. My solution works (just a different approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your first search criterion with:

```
spanishdict_soup.find("span", {"id": "dictionary-link-es"}).text
```

Comment: You might also want to consider using `raw_input` for strings (so you don't have to wrap the input in double-quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the data can be found in the `script` tags as a json format. It's just amatter of pulling that out and then grabbing what you need. I couldn't see where to get it from the source html other than inside the script tag:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/"
search_keyword = input("input the keyword : ")

url = base_url + search_keyword
spanishdict_r = requests.get(url)
spanishdict_soup = BeautifulSoup(spanishdict_r.text, 'html.parser')


scripts = spanishdict_soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'SD_DICTIONARY_RESULTS_PROPS' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('global.SD_DICTIONARY_RESULTS_PROPS = ')[-1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';\n')[0]
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)



# Phonetic Alphabet
print(jsonData['es']['pronunciationDictionaryLink']['pronunciationSpellings'][0])
# Part of Speech
print(jsonData['es']['entry']['neodictFullQuickPartOfSpeechEn'])
# Meaning
```

**Output:**

```
input the keyword : que
keh
conjunction
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have got an error.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spanishdict2.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(jsonData['es']['pronunciationDictionaryLink']['pronunciationSpellings'][0])
KeyError: 'es'

Comment: hmmm. That means it's being returned differently (without the `'es'` key). Can I ask are you connecting from US and/or UK?